# how to remove characters from \n to end in a string

Tags: dart

I have this string `"Something\nhors réseau\n+ que 3e"` and I want to remove from `\n` until the end of the string keeping only `"Something"`

How can I achieve this with dart?

Comment: What have you tried?  This should be pretty straightforward with [`String.indexOf`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/String/indexOf.html) and [`String.substring`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/String/substring.html).  Alternatively [`String.split`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/String/split.html).

Comment: I added an answer, thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subString`

```
var string = "Something\nhors réseau\n+ que 3e" ;
  var indexOfSlashN = string.indexOf("\n");
  var reducedString = string.substring(0, indexOfSlashN);
  print(reducedString);
```

Comment: This is a good answer :) but then again, I think mine is more valid since dart has it's own method, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, LineSplitter is good, but if you check the ```covert``` method for LineSplitter, you'd notice it takes time to convert it to a List. @JoséNobre

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `indexOf` and `substring`:

```dart
String input = 'Something\nhors réseau\n+ que 3e';
String output = input.substring(0, input.indexOf('\n'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out dart has a class that does this for us you just need to do :

```
    String name = "Something\nhors réseau\n+ que 3e";
    LineSplitter ls = new LineSplitter();
    List<String> lines = ls.convert(name);
    print(lines[0]) // Something
```

Comment: `LineSplitter` was designed to be a stream transformer. To use it on a regular string would be overkill compared to just using `split` on the string itself.